# DataFrames: storing and querying arrays of keywords

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'm wondering whether dataframes are suitable for a task which involves the storage of a varying number of keywords for each record. Here's a minimum working example:

```
using DataFrames, Query

df = DataFrame()

df[:Name]  =  ["Alice", "Arthur", "Bob", "Charlie"]
df[:Diet]  =  [["apple", "orange", "onion"], 
               [], 
               ["banana", "onion", "cake"], 
               ["olives", "peanut butter", "avocado"]]
df[:Weight] = [70, 90, 80, 60]
```

Using Query.jl:

```
julia> q1 = @from i in df begin
            @where startswith(get(i.Name), "A")
            @select {i.Name, i.Diet, i.Weight}
            @collect DataFrame
       end
2×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Name     │ Diet                   │ Weight │
├─────┼──────────┼────────────────────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ "Alice"  │ Any["apple", "orange"] │ 70     │
│ 2   │ "Arthur" │ Any[]                  │ 90     │
```

But how to ask queries involving keywords. For example, who eats onions?

```
julia> q2 = @from i in df begin
            # @where ??? a keyword in i.Diet starting with "on"?
            @select {i.Name, i.Diet, i.Weight}
            @collect DataFrame
       end
```

I know [Query.jl](https://github.com/davidanthoff/Query.jl) is able to work with databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@where` clause is a Julia expression, so functions like `any` and dot-notation can be used. Specifically:

```
julia> q2 = @from i in df begin
            @where any(startswith.(get(i.Diet), "on"))
            @select {i.Name, i.Diet, i.Weight}
            @collect DataFrame
       end
2×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Name    │ Diet                            │ Weight │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ "Alice" │ Any["apple", "orange", "onion"] │ 70     │
│ 2   │ "Bob"   │ Any["banana", "onion", "cake"]  │ 80     │
```